# How use AutoMapper correctly in a layered architecture?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

How do I even use `AutoMapper` correctly in a **layered architecture** and where do I initialize it if my path described below is not correct?

[There is a solution screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xeun.png)
for the sake of a common understanding :)

As you can see, there are `DTO's`, `Models` and `ViewModels` in different layers

I want a mapping from **DAL** to **BLL** and then to (*console*)**PL** and conversely

But I get
`AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping'`

can't find any similar examples for me

Thanks in advance

Here is an example of how I connect `AutoMapper` for `ViewModel`->`DTO` mapping, maybe this is not the right way?
I have the same way `AutoMapper` is connected in **BLL** for mapping `DTO`->`Model`

```
private IMapper _mapper;
private readonly BLL.BookService _bookService;

public UiBookService(UserDTO currentUser)
{
    _mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<BookViewModel, BookDTO>()).CreateMapper();
    _bookService = new BLL.BookService(currentUser);
    CurrentUser = currentUser;
}
```

then use it like this

```
await _bookService.CreateBook(_mapper.Map<BookDTO>(book));
```

`BLL.BookService`: (*This is where this error occurs*)

```
public async Task CreateBook(BookDTO book)
{
    book.OwnerId = _currentUser.Id;
    await _bookRepo.CreateAsync(_mapper.Map<Book>(book));
}
```

In this `UiBookService`, we create a `BookViewModel` from the console and pass it as `BookDTO` to `BookService` from **BLL**.
The strange thing is that in `DTO` the mapping goes fine, but in **BLL** it doesn't map from `DTO` to a normal `Model`

Comment: Start by following the [AutoMapper Usage Guidelines](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/). And then consider if the only reason you are using AutoMapper is because others do: if you do not have a direct immediate reason for a dependency, then do not take that dependency.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

I would create two [MappingConfig](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html) files.

- Model <-> DTO in BLL.Mapping
- DTO <-> ViewModel in PL.Mapping

This will allow you to test your mappings and use one mapping for the same signature among the whole program. Also, make sure that all mappings between entities are configured.

After that, inject them in a DI container.